# Incorrect header check error when trying to run (any) Maven build

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am having some problem with IntelliJ whereas running any Maven Build throws "*incorrect header check*" error, what could be causing this?

I have already deleted the jar in the `.m2` folder to check if that will fix it but it didn't.

[image]

Comment: Does it happen only in IntelliJ IDEA? Can you run the same goal from the command line Maven?  Any more details in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)?

Comment: Yes, it only happens on IntelliJ, running on command line works just fine, I cannot post the idea.log file in the post because it is too long, here's the log https://pastebin.com/ehBmK4Wv

Comment: Delete IDE [system directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519). Try [2018.1.1 release](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks, the issue seems to be intermittent, I closed the IDE and opened it again and works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Intellij Idea, close and reopen IDE. it works for me.